# Problems installng/uninstalling 'Visual Studio Community 2013 with Update 5'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I've been having problems installing/uninstalling visual studio, the first time, I successfully installed it, but then I realised I had no use for it and needed the older version. I tried uninstalling it, but the loading bar wasn't moving after 10 mins, so I deleted the files from \Program Files (x86)\ instead.

So I went on and installed visual c++ 2010 express. But the next day,(after failing at everything) I found I **did** in fact need VS community 2013, so I downloaded the installer and it failed to install a couple things that didn't matter, but when I tried to find where VS installed, there were only the extra bundle programs, and not VS, so I figured I'd have to fully uninstall it.

I've tried uninsalling it, but it failed.

I've tried force uninstalling it, but all that did was try to reinstall it.

At the moment I'm do the sfc /scannow command

Info About my PC:

OS: Windows 10 Home

System Type: 64-bit OS, x64-based processor

Here's a log from when I tried to repair (or reinstall it, I can't remember) it:

http://pastebin.com/AbknK9PL

Comment: Why not install Visual Studio Community 2015?

Comment: *but then I realised I had no use for it and needed the older version* -- Why did you think you needed an older version?

Comment: I want to make a mod for Source sdk 2013, and valve does not support visual studio 2015 yet

Comment: Paul Mckenzie, I thought I needed the 2010 version because it told me so on  the valve developer wiki, but it turns out that its outdated

Comment: @J.Czekaj What developers do when it comes to Visual Studio is to install multiple versions of the compiler (of course using different installation directories), not uninstall their current version.  You should have just installed whatever version you needed without touching your current installation.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it.

1. Intsall VS 2013
2. uninstall it
3. reboot
4. delete VS from program files
5. install VS 2013